# Answer the bot [discord.py]

Tags: discord, discord.py

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr9ak.png)hi i would like to ask one tiny question

example:

when you write a message

so I'll respond to YOUR message

if there is a command in response to your message

bot will reply to a message you wrote

image explambe [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr9ak.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example,

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.reply("reply message")
```

Make sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the discord.py [documentations](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#manuals)

Comment: In this case, reply to the message referenced by using message.reference.message_id
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.MessageReference

Comment: I don't know how to do it